# What is fixed_frame_rate_flag used for in encoders?

Tags: h.264, frame-rate, mpeg

There is a flag called the fixed_frame_rate_flag used in encoders. I haven't been able to find any clear explanation of what this is, and what its significance is. The flag can either be set to 0 or 1, but I don't know what this would imply.

Any help, information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed frame rate is the opposite of variable frame rate. If a video is fixed frame rate, every frame has a predictable timestamp. `timestamp = frame_number * frame_rate`. If its variable, every frame has its own duration and some frames may displayed for longer or shorter periods and has an unpredictable time stamp.

Comment: Thank you @szatmary ! Well just to understand this better I tried the following on two separate .ts files. One of them with fixed_frame_rate_flag set to 0 and the other set to 1. I used ffprobe -show_frames [ts filename] | grep pkt_pts_time and worked out the deltas to see if they were constant or irregular. I found both .ts files to have irregular deltas between successive pts times... Not sure if my assumption is wrong